# how to make sure mocked object is called only once in mockito

Tags: java, loops, mocking, mockito

I have a while loop as follows

```
while (nodeIterator.hasNext())
```

I have mocked this method hasNext to return true so that I can test the code inside while loop  but now the problem is everytime it returns true and this loop will never end. Please tell me is there anyway by which I can make sure that this method is called only once, or if not then how can I return false after first execution

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got the answer we can do it in the following way

```
when(nodeIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
```

this is known as method stubbing. Similarly if you want to call it twice and then you want to return false, then do as follows

```
when(nodeIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
```

Answer (score 8):

see [OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(T,T...)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenReturn(T,%20T...))

this way you can return values for a sequence of calls.

```
when(nodeIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true,false);
```

above returns true on the first call and false on every subsequent call.

Comment: mentioned link is longer available